# Regular Expression allow whitspace without counting them

Tags: regex

How to get

- `[\d ]{6}`

to match:

- `1 23456`
- `1 2 3456`
- `1 2 3 456`
- `1 2 3 4 56`
- `1 2 3 4 5 6`

In other words, I would like the space to not be counted towards the char limit. Something like `[\d]{6 + but allow spaces you can eat}`

Comment: Something like `(?:\s*\d){6}`, `(?:\s?\d){6}` or [`^(?:\s*\d){6}\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/TrNUT7/1).

Comment: Daniel, I would have posted an answer, but your requirements are unclear. Please provide full specs. Else, review the answers below (melwil's and Jan's are of interest), they may be enough for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will match 6 numbers, with any amount of space characters between them.

```
(?:\d\s*){5}\d
```

`?:` at the beginning there makes the group non-capturing. It's not necessary if all you wish to do is a simple match.

A live example:

https://regex101.com/r/PZJ8DO/2

Comment: This will allow spaces after the last digit; to prevent that: `(?:\d\s*){5}\d`

Comment: Depends a lot what they will use this for, but I agree with you. Updated the answer.

Comment: thank you, this is perfect. I just don't get why it works. Why are whitespaces not counted?

Comment: The white space is counted. The group repeated 5 times includes one number `\d`, and any amount of white space `\s*`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
(?<=).*6.*
```

This will match any line that contains '6' even if there are some white spaces or other characters in the line.

The (?<=) Positive Look Behind.

The . matches any character except line breaks.

The * matches 0 or more of the preceding token.

And 6 matches a "6" Character.

You can test Regular Expression here: [RegExr](https://regexr.com/)

Note that the positive look behind feature is not supported in all flavors of RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Just to put my two cents in: you could use the opposite of `\d` which is `\D` in most flavors:

```
^(?:\d\D*){6}$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/hTV4uI/1/).

---

Note, that this would even allow something like

```
1a2b3c4d5e6
```

If this is not what you want (meaning you only want to allow spaces, nothing else), use `\s*` instead of `\D*`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Sadly, I can only allow spaces and nothing more